# The server quit without updating PID file

Tags: mysql, osx-mavericks, pid

I am trying to install MySQL on my Mac w/ Mavericks OS. Whenever I try `sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start` it shows an error `The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/mysql/data/computername.local.pid`)

I've seen this error many times in the internet, but they solutions don't help me.

I have tried the following steps:

1. Granting myself ownership of the `err` file
2. Deleting it manually
3. Creating the PID file

What happens is that after creating the PID file, starting MySQL server shows `SUCCESS` status. But then after that, the PID file gets deleted and the err file either shows up again if deleted or just removes my ownership. It is really frustrating.

Is there another work around for installing MySQL on OS X Mavericks?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, have you ever found a solution?

Comment: Nope I haven't. I now have a macbook with Mountain Lion and everything works perfectly. But I think I came across something in the internet about the installation of MySQL at OS X Mavericks when I already got myself a Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the `computername.local.pid` by doing the following:

```
rm *.err /usr/local/mysql/data/
```

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser.  Your [answer](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) would be even better if you edit it to provide some explanation as to *why* your solution addresses the OPs question.